# how do i cast an abstract list to it's concrete type

Tags: c#, list, abstract

i have the following setup;

```
public abstract class StageObject
{
}
public class StageImage : StageObject
{
    public int Image;
}
public class StageStrip : StageObject
{
    public int Strip;
}
```

i do the following;

```
StageList = new List<StageObject>();
StageList.Add(new StageStrip());
StageList.Add(new StageImage());
```

i would love to be able to cast the array element as it's concrete type like this but i get an error;

```
(StageStrip) StageList[0].Strip = 2;
```

the only way i can do this is to create a temporary variable and cast it to the array. is there a way i can do it without creating the temporary variable?

Comment: You're getting an error because of order of precedence. What C# is doing is its getting `StageList[0].Strip`, which is an `int` and trying to cast it to a type of `StageStrip`, and since C# doesn't know how to convert an `int` into type `StageStrip`, its giving you an error. Surround `(StageStrip)StageList[0]` in parenthesis and it should work.

Answer (score 8):

```
((StageStrip)StageList[0]).Strip = 2;
```

Comment: Just for added information, if for some reason you want to cast them all, you may find `.Cast<T>()` useful. Or `.OfType<T>()` if they may not all be - which tends to be more useful.